# Selecting values from last six hours

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp

First thing, my date format for the field is `TIMESTAMP`

I have a table that consists of id, domain, hits, when.

Now when I insert the hits into the database, i'm pulling from my analytics API every 10 minutes. So the content of this table is

```
id=1, domain=test.com, hits=930, when=2011-11-22 16:00:22;

id=2, domain=test2.com, hits=134, when=2011-11-22 16:10:22;
```

etc

Once this fills up with data every 10 minutes for the last six hours, I want to find the number of hits for each domain for each *hour*. so:

There will be 6 rows per hour since it inserts every 10 minutes, how can I retrieve the total number of hits for each hour?

If I want to pull my statistics at 1:39PM for the current hour, I should be able to pull all the hits from 1:10PM, 1:20PM, 1:30PM.

DO I need six separate mysql queries that take the current time and run it for each hour because I was be displaying it in a graph (1 hour ago, 2 hours ago, 3 hours ago, etc) or is there a simpler way to achieve this?

Please help me understand, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try

```
select domain, date_format(when, '%Y-%m-%d %I%p') hour, sum(hits)
from table group by domain, hour
```

**EDIT:** I changed the format from `%H` for 24 hour clock to `%I%p` for 12 hour clock with AM/PM, since it seems like that's what you want.

**EDIT2:** If it's only the last six hours you want, grouped by how many hours ago the hits were, you might be better off with (added date_format to group by whole hour)

```
select domain, hour(timediff(date_format(now(), '%Y-%m-%d %H'), 
    date_format(when, '%Y-%m-%d %H'))) hours, sum(hits)
from table
where hours < 7
group by domain, hours
```

Comment: Thank you! This seems to be the proper way to do it, will this show every hour? Is there anyway to limit it to the last 6 hours?

Comment: @Michael: My pleasure. The first one will give you ISO date and 12 hour clock hour, but not limit anything. The second query will give you only the last 6 hours and group by which hour the hit appeared in.

Comment: I forgot to mention, that hits stay constant so for id=1, hits=450   id=2, hits=520  so from id 1=>2 (10 minutes) there was 70 hits in 10 minutes. How would this be done?

Comment: @Michael: So the hits always increase for a specific domain within the hour, then starts at 0 the next hour? If so, just replace `sum` with `max`. This should work since we used date_format to truncate the datetime to whole hours. That is of course assuming that one domain only has one id for any given hour.

Comment: It doesn't start back at 0 for the next hour, it keeps increasing. It's for monthly statistics, after a month I will just empty and start over

Comment: @Michael: Then maybe you can replace `sum(hits)` with `max(hits) - min(hits)`. I'm not sure if that works though, and I don't currently have a test database available.